# Umbraco Macro form doesn't respect selection choice

Tags: xslt, umbraco

I recently inherited a 'nearly' finished Umbraco build, and one of our content editors ran into this issue.
The CMS has a macro, for showing a link to the user account login, with a single check box to display or hide this macro on the front end.

However, whichever choice the user makes, the block always displays on the page.

I'm completely new to Umbraco, so be kind. 
My predecessor has written the xslt file for the Macro as below.
My first thought was that the $currentPage/showAccountLogin is wrong, but I have no idea in what way.

```
<xsl:param name="currentPage"/>

<xsl:template match="/">

<xsl:if test="$currentPage/showAccountLogin=true()">
<div class="related-content">
  <h3>Login to your account</h3>
  <ul><li>Access your account or retrieve<br />your login details<br /><a href="#">Go to your account <img src="/images/external.gif" alt="External Link (Opens in new window)" /></a></li></ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to the call a macro to return true or false from within some XSLT? That won't work, as the syntax that you're using there is for checking a page level variable.

$currentPage/showAccountLogin

The above looks for a page level property called "showAccountLogin", it won't run a Macro with the alias of "ShowAccountLogin". It doesn't look like the code you've posted is the login code anyway. If you'd like some more information on how to code a login with Umbraco, check out this tutorial: [Umbraco Membership Templates](http://www.blogfodder.co.uk/2011/12/31/umbraco-membership-templates)

If you just want to check if a user is logged in, there is an Umbrcao library method you can call in your XSLT, like this:

```
<xsl:if test="umbraco.library:IsLoggedOn() = true()">
  I'M LOGGED IN!!!
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer, the Macro shows a link to the login page, not the actual login.

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks for updating, but this isn't really what I'm looking for. The admin page has a checkbox to hide or display a box that links to the login page on the front end. My predecessor has written this as `$currentPage/showAccoutLogin=true()` which is wrong. I'm hoping to find out how to write this correctly.

Comment: Ahhh, you should have made that clearer in your original post! try:

$currentPage/showAccountLogin = 1

In the if statement

Comment: Sorry Tim, I realised it wasn't clear and changed the question just before you posted! That worked! Thanks!

Comment: Never look the gift horse in the mouth! :D